# In the top banner shown to users who haven't logged in, the site description is inaccurate on per-site metas

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta, wording, notification-bar

Let's take a look at the text in the top banner of [Ask Ubuntu Meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com):

> Ask Ubuntu Meta is a question and answer site for Ubuntu users and developers. It only takes a minute to sign up.

[image]

Well, **Ask Ubuntu Meta** is not really a Q&A site for Ubuntu users and developers. It's a site for Ask Ubuntu users to discuss about Ask Ubuntu.

This is not just the case in Ask Ubuntu; I think it's the same case for all child metas. Another example (from Database Administrators Meta Stack Exchange):

> Database Administrators Meta Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community. It only takes a minute to sign up.

I'm not really sure about what could be the appropriate replacement text. Please share your thoughts!